# map box is not working with expo react native, what is the alternative ?

Tags: react-native, mapbox, expo

I found out that map box is not yet supported in expo. Can map box be integrated in react native app without expo ? Or is there any other alternative for map box that works with expo and react native while i need to show custom routes and locations on the map ?

Answer (score 1):

Expo has MapView support - check it out in Expo documentation. If you want to use Mapbox you can detach from expo and add a library from Mapbox (it has some native code, so detach is necessary).

Comment: js is needed, native android we can do but native ios we cant do

Comment: @syam could you tell how to do this?